# Convert JRuby string to Java byte array, and back again

Tags: jruby

I'm trying to pass a binary string in JRuby as a `byte[]` through some Java library and into JRuby again, where I want to convert it back into a string, but I can't figure out how to do it without the string getting messed up.

Specifically I'm encoding a Ruby hash as BSON and passing it over AMQP, but it's the conversion to and from `byte[]` that doesn't work. This code

```
import org.jruby.RubyString
blob = BSON.serialize({'test' => 123123123123}).to_s
p blob
p RubyString.bytes_to_string(RubyString.string_to_bytes(blob))
```

outputs

```
"\x13\x00\x00\x00\x12test\x00\xB3\xC3\xB5\xAA\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\x13\x00\x00\x00\x12test\x00\xC2\xB3\xC3\x83\xC2\xB5\xC2\xAA\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

I have also tried

```
java.lang.String.new(blob.to_java.bytes).to_s
```

but it outputs the same, wrong, string.

Is there any easier/safer way to convert to and from a JRuby string and `byte[]`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the answer myself, turned out there was a `#to_java_bytes` on `String`, and a helper method `.from_java_bytes` that handle the conversion without issue:

```
blob = BSON.serialize({'test' => 123123123123}).to_s
p blob
p String.from_java_bytes(blob.to_java_bytes)
```

Comment: Can you explain more? How to import BSON. I am not able to execute it on BSON. I want to convert String to a byte array in ruby

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already, this works:

```
irb(main):002:0> String.from_java_bytes(java_bytes)
=> "\x01\x02\x03"
```

But this also works:

```
irb(main):003:0> java_bytes.to_s
=> "\x01\x02\x03"
```

And I would argue that it's more sensible. :D